# Convert S to T by performing K operations (HackerRank)

Tags: string, python-3.x, algorithm, logic

I was solving a problem on HackerRank. It required me to see if it is possible to convert string `s` to string `t` by performing `k` operations. 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/append-and-delete/problem

The operations we can perform are: appending a lowercase letter to the end of `s` or removing a lowercase letter from the end of `s`. For example `Ash Ashley 2` would return `No` since we need 3 operations, not 2.

I tried solving the problem as follows:

```
def appendAndDelete(s, t, k):
    if len(s) > len(t):
        maxs = [s,t]
    else:
        maxs = [t,s]

    maximum = maxs[0]
    minimum = maxs[1]
    k -= len(maximum) - len(minimum)
    substr = maximum[len(minimum): len(maximum)]
    maximum = maximum.replace(substr, '')

    i = 0
    while i < len(maximum):
        if maximum[i] != minimum[i]:
            k -= (len(maximum)-i)*2
            break
        i += 1
    if k < 0:
        return 'No'
    else:
        return 'Yes'
```

However, it fails at this weird test case. `y yu 2`. The expected answer is `No` but according to my code, it would return `Yes` since only one operation was required. Is there something I do not understand?

Comment: You have to use exactly k operations.

Comment: keep performing editing operations until you hit 'k'. In case of unequal characters at i, j ( indices of s, t ) there will be two paths : append, delete - traverse each path but keep a track of the length of the path you traversed. If it is equal to k don't go further. If at any point before k you could get equal strings, return true.

Comment: Actually I take back "If at any point before k you could get equal strings, return true." Check at the kth level of the tree if the strings are equal then return true otherwise false.

Comment: Explain your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since you don't explain your idea, it's difficult for us to understand
> what you mean in your code and debug it to tell you where you went wrong.

However, I would like to share my idea(I solved this on the website too)-

`len1` => Length of first string `s`.

`len2` => Length of second/target string `t`.

- **Exactly K** makes it a bit tricky. So, if `len1 + len2 <= k`, you can blindly assume it can be accomplished and return `true` since we can delete empty string many times to get an empty string(as it says) and we can delete characters of one string entirely and keep appending new letters to get the another.
- When we start matching `s` with `t` from left to right, this looks more like `longest common prefix` but this is **NOT** the case. Let's take an example -

> ```
> aaaaaaaaa (source)
> aaaa (target)
> 7 (k)
> ```

Here, up till `aaaa` it's common and looks like there are additional `5 a's` in the source. So, we can delete those 5 a's and get the target but 5 != 7, hence it appears to be a `No`. But this ain't the case since we **can delete an `a` from the source just like that and append it again(2 operations) just to satisfy k.** So, it need not be longest common prefix all the time, however it gets us closer to the solution.

- So, let's match both strings from left to right and stop when there is a mismatch. Let's assume we got this index in a variable called `first_unmatched`. Initialize `first_unmatched = min(len(s),len(t))` at the beginning of your method itself.

Let

> rem1 = len1 - first_unmatched
>
> rem2 = len2 - first_unmatched

where `rem1` is remaining substring of `s` and `rem2` is the remaining substring of `t`.

Now, comes the conditions.

- `if(rem1 + rem2 == k) return true`-
  This is because `rem1` characters to delete and `rem2` characters to add. If both sum up to `k` then it's possible.
- `if(rem1 + rem2 > k) return false`-
  This is because `rem1` characters to delete and `rem2` characters to add. If both sum greater than `k` then it's not possible.
- `if(rem1 + rem2 < k) return (k - (rem1 + rem2)) % 2 == 0`-
  This is because `rem1` characters to delete and `rem2` characters to add. If both sum less than `k`, then it depends.

Here, `(k - (rem1 + rem2))` will give you **the extra in k**. This extra can or cannot depends upon whether it's divisible by 2 or not. Here, we do **%2** because we have `2` operations in our question - `delete` and `append`. If **the extra k** falls short of any operation, then the answer is `No`, else it's a `Yes`.

You can cross check this with above example.